# How to add a new user with role to database/ Hibernate, Spring Security, Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem with adding a new user with the role to the database. I just do not know how to do it. I'm using Spring Security 5, hibernate 5, Spring MVC. Everywhere finds how to log in but not how to add a new one. I would ask for some hints. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find many tutorials which will demonstrate ways to configure a Spring MVC application for  user creation/registration.  Here is one that you may find very useful.  It also makes the full codebase available.  [Spring Security - Roles and Privileges](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration). The best way to learn is did in and start building some experience.  There is obviously more than one may to design your back end and dao layer.  Good Luck.

Comment: I know this example but it is probably too difficult for me. I would prefer a simple example where everything is from the database to the controller. This will allow me to see how it connects.